# REST request times out after making several database connections

Tags: performance, rest, database-connection, restlet

I have a REST application that uses RESTlets. I am querying several databases to create a response with the queried data.  The process of closing and opening database connections takes sometimes 20 seconds each.  Sometimes my procedure makes 10 different database connections (to different databases).  The browser times out after this time because this is obviously too long for a client to wait for the response.

How can I retrieve data from these different databases in a single batch without getting this time out.  How can I speed up this process to be under the timeout threshold of the browser?

Comment: @alfasin why did you post that?

Comment: some of the cases, there is no direct solution, and so I don't want to answer the question with an alternative, but the actual solution to the questions asked.  I will update any I found with a direct solution.  Thanks for keeping this site awesome!

Comment: @alfasin how do you like my answer?

Comment: @Atma The point is that people see you rarely accept answers and so aren't going to be included to answer other questions you post.  Part of the motiviation for answering questions is the reputation gotten by being upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing memcached with a long timeout.  Now I only do this extensive query once and it is cached for several hours.